# jQuery drag event is not working on touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, touch

I am using jQuery drag event its working fine in browsers but not working in touch screens. While I am using this below code (found in stackoverflow). its working but its blocking the input elements.

I need to work on input elements as well as drag event with touch support, 
Please help me out with this issue

```
  <!-- touch functions -->

     function touchHandler(event) {
        var touch = event.changedTouches[0];

        var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
        simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent({
            touchstart: "mousedown",
            touchmove: "mousemove",
            touchend: "mouseup"
        }[event.type], true, true, window, 1,
                touch.screenX, touch.screenY,
                touch.clientX, touch.clientY, false,
                false, false, false, 0, null);

        touch.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    function init() {
        document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
        document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
        document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
        document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);
    }
 // -- call **init()** in document.ready function
```

Comment: You could try [jquery.udraggable](http://grantm.github.io/jquery-udraggable/)

Comment: Thanks Grant McLean, I have seen  undraggable, but its not working, I have created a dummy page with jQuery min file and the undraggable js, do i have to include anything else ??